# Ensuring right order of operations in random forest classification in scikit learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I would like to ensure that the order of operations for my machine learning is right:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

# 1. Initialize model
model = RandomForestClassifier(5000)

# 2. Load dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

# 3. Remove unimportant features
model = SelectFromModel(model, threshold=0.5).estimator

# 4. cross validate model on the important features
k_fold = KFold(n=len(data), n_folds=10, shuffle=True)
for k, (train, test) in enumerate(k_fold):
    self.model.fit(data[train], target[train])

# 5. grid search for best parameters
param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [1000, 2500, 5000],
    'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
    'max_depth': [3, 5, data.shape[1]]
}

gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid)
gs.fit(X, y)
model = gs.best_estimator_

# Now the model can be used for prediction
```

Please let me know if this order looks good or if something can be done to improve it.

--EDIT, clarifying to reduce downvotes.

Specifically,
1. Should the `SelectFromModel` be done after cross validation?

2. Should grid search be done before cross validation?

Comment: Does that code run? I don't believe you can call `predict()` on `SelectFromModel` as would be required for `GridSearch`. From the doc it appears `SelectFromModel` is a transformer, not an estimator.

Comment: thanks @DavidMaust, I had a typo there. It runs once I do this `SelectFromModel(model, threshold=0.5).estimator`

Comment: modified code to `SelectFromModel(model, threshold=0.5).estimator`

Comment: I believe in that case `SelectFromModel` does nothing. You are wrapping your estimator with `SelectFromModel` and then unwrapping it.

Comment: thanks @DavidMaust, if you could point a way to fix that, I would be happy to accept it as answer.

Comment: Sure. I'll write you up a quick answer. You need to use a pipeline though. Answer coming shortly....

Comment: thank you so much! would also appreciate your input on whether the order in which the various steps are being performed is correct.

Comment: In my answer below, that is the correct process. The biggest mistake you could make is putting the `GridSearchCV` after a feature selection stage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem with your approach is you are confusing the feature selection transformer with the final estimator. What you will need to do is create two stages, the transformer first:

```
rf_feature_imp = RandomForestClassifier(100)
feat_selection = SelectFromModel(rf_feature_imp, threshold=0.5)
```

Then you need a second phase where you use the reduced feature set to train a classifier on the reduced feature set.

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(5000)
```

Once you have your phases, you can build a pipeline to combine the two into a final model.

```
model = Pipeline([
          ('fs', feat_selection), 
          ('clf', clf), 
        ])
```

Now you can perform a `GridSearch` on your `model`. Keep in mind you have two stages, so the parameters must be specified by stage `fs` or `clf`. In terms of the feature selection stage, you can also access the base estimator using `fs__estimator`. Below is an example of how to search parameters on any of the three objects.

```
 params = {
    'fs__threshold': [0.5, 0.3, 0.7],
    'fs__estimator__max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
    'clf__max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
 }

 gs = GridSearchCV(model, params, ...)
 gs.fit(X,y)
```

You can then make predictions with `gs` directly or using `gs.best_estimator_`.

Comment: One note. I wouldn't generally search RandomForest's `n_estimators` for the best number. Typically it will always be the highest. You may, however, want to test it so you can build a faster or smaller model.

Comment: thank you so much David Maust, this really is a super great answer

Comment: one query, where does cross validation fit into this? i.e. when should i do that

Comment: GridSearchCV automatically performs k-fold cross validation by default in order to select the best parameters.  You can view these scores using `gs.best_score_` or `gs.grid_scores_`. This will give you an estimate, but it may be skewed high because it is the best of many runs with many parameters. If you want a more precise estimate, you should hold out some of your data at the very beginning, and run `gs.score(test_X, test_y)` at the end for better estimate.

Comment: thanks again @David Maust, I have a corollary to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376293/extracting-selected-feature-names-from-scikit-pipeline. Appreciate if you could take a look