# Extracting selected feature names from scikit pipeline

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

```
# Load dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

rf_feature_imp = RandomForestClassifier(100)
feat_selection = SelectFromModel(rf_feature_imp, threshold=0.5)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(5000)

model = Pipeline([
          ('fs', feat_selection), 
          ('clf', clf), 
        ])

 params = {
    'fs__threshold': [0.5, 0.3, 0.7],
    'fs__estimator__max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
    'clf__max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
 }

 gs = GridSearchCV(model, params, ...)
 gs.fit(X,y)
```

The above code is based on [Ensuring right order of operations in random forest classification in scikit learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256876/ensuring-right-order-of-operations-in-random-forest-classification-in-scikit-lea)

Since I am using SelectFromModel, I would like to print the names of the features that were selected (in the SelectFromModel pipeline), but not sure how to extract them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to call the feature selector's `transform()` on the feature names, but it has to be presented the feature names in the form of an list of examples.

First you must obtain the feature selection phase from the best estimator found in the `GridSearchCV`.

```
fs = gs.best_estimator_.named_steps['fs']
```

Create an example list from the feature_names:

```
feature_names_example = [iris.feature_names]
```

Use the feature selector to transform this example.

```
selected_features = fs.transform(feature_names_example)

print selected_features[0] # Select the one example
# ['sepal length (cm)' 'petal length (cm)' 'petal width (cm)']
```

Comment: The 0.7 for `fs__threshold` in this code causes the following error for me on scikit-learn 0.17.1 and Python 2.7 and the `load_iris` dataset. The line `gs.fit(X,y)` produces the following error C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\base.py:80: UserWarning: No features were selected: either the data is too noisy or the selection test too strict. UserWarning) Traceback (most recent call last): ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(99, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required. I found that if 0.7 is removed, the code runs as expected. Seems weird but at least it runs.

Comment: Yes. That would make sense if there were no features with an importance of > 0.7 which wouldn't be surprising. RandomForestClassifier also is not deterministic if no `random_state` is given.

Answer (score 6):

[`SelectFromModel`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html) has a [`get_support()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.get_support) method that returns a boolean mask for the features that were selected. So you could do (in addition to the preliminary step described by @David Maust):

```
feature_names = np.array(iris.feature_names)
selected_features = feature_names[fs.get_support()]
```

Answer (score 1):

**s=model.named_steps['fs'].fit(X,y)**

**X.columns[s.get_support()]**